# C++ Multi threading

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am writing a DLL out for a call of duty game and I got a lot working but my trouble is with my code below:

```
int func = 0;
-----
if (cl_ingame=1){ Sleep(35);start(); }

void start()
{
command(x,x, "c \"Press up for 11th\"");
func = 1;
Sleep(3000); 
command(x,x, "c \"Press up for Unlock all\"");
func = 2;

if (dpad = up){
if (func = 1){
do11th();
}else if (func = 2){
doUnlock();
} 
}
```

Now it's not the code it self that is troubled it's the fact that the void "start" is going to be a loop, now my issue is I'm unable to use any controls or call any functions if the game is already busy looping one, so I need to find out how to thread for C++

I know google is mans best friend but it does not really explain very detailed, if someone can just simply give me a example thread Like so

(THREAD)
{
functions
}

How to stop thread and how to call / start thread

Thanks so much for help

Comment: http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-1-starting-threads.html ...

Comment: you should look into boost threads

Comment: The code and the question is very unclear. So basically you want to know how to start and stop a thread? If so then there are numerous examples and tutorials on the net. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: All I need to do is know how to put functions or code inside of a seprite thread so I can call many functions at once without waiting for one to finish, then a way to start / stop the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Starting a thread is very simple:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void thread_entry(int arg)
{
    std::cout << "Thread running: argument " << arg << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Thread starting" << std::endl;
    std::thread thread(thread_entry, 42);
    thread.join();
    std::cout << "Thread finished" << std::endl;
}
```

Communicating with a thread while it's running is more involved. Unfortunately, Standard C++ is still rather lacking in high-level concurrency, so to start with it's probably easiest to use the atomic variables, mutexes and condition variables offered by the standard library. To simply stop the thread:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

void thread_entry(std::atomic<bool> & stop)
{
    while (!stop) {
        std::cout << "Thread running" << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Thread starting" << std::endl;
    std::atomic<bool> stop(false);
    std::thread thread(thread_entry, std::ref(stop));
    sleep(5);
    stop = true;
    thread.join();
    std::cout << "Thread finished" << std::endl;
}
```

In general, synchronisation between threads is complicated, and easy to get wrong. Take care to minimise the amount of data shared between threads, and think very carefully about everything you do with that data, making sure it's never being accessed by one thread while another might change it.

If you're writing a game, then a simpler approach might be a single-threaded event loop. A single main loop would poll for input events and notify the various components of the program that they have happened; they would update their state accordingly and perhaps generate more events of their own. The only complication is that each event handler must do its work quickly to avoid blocking the whole program.

Comment: Thanks for long detailed post! do you have a Skype I will send you my main class so you have a better understanding of my  issues.

Comment: Noted, starting a thread using C++11 or boost is simple. Nowhere in the OP's question did he mention the toolset he was using. Excellent sample if he's using C++11, however. And congrats, Mr. Seymour; it's a boy!